# How to set dialog title gravity?

Tags: android, dialog, material-design, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to set dialog title gravity to right as i'm showing arabic text. Please check attached image.

[image: Click here]

So, i want to show title text to right. Please suggest me the way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prepare a custom View and and use it for your dialog!

Comment: @Xenolion: I want to use default dialog and in that want to set title right side.

Comment: Is it an AlertDialog? or?

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);

Comment: Okay my answer if it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can see you are using Arabic which is `RTL` you can customize your whole `AlertDialog` to be Right to Left this will be helpful in the future if you want to twist code to `RTL`.

Okay do this **:**

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

//We first check if it is above or equal Jelly Bean and setLayoutDirection

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the `setCustomTitle` method to supply your own TextView:

```
TextView mTitle = new TextView(this);
mTitle.setText("My Title");
mTitle.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCustomTitle(mTitle)
    .create()
    .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView mTitle = new TextView(this);
mTitle.setText("کاربر گرامی به جهت الزما جهت استفاده از برنامه لطفا اطلاعات صحیح وارد نماید");
mTitle.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
mTitle.setPadding(10,20,20,10);
mTitle.setTextSize(14);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_get_user_info, null);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

alertDialog.setCustomTitle(mTitle);
// alertDialog.setIcon("Icon id here");
alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
// Constant.alertDialog.setMessage("Your Message Here");

final EditText etComments = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailAddress);

alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ثبت", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    showMessage("پیام");
  }
});
```